How can I show the MudSelect text instead of the MudSelect value of the currently selected item?
I have the following MudSelect drop down in my blazor code:
<div class="w3-col m12 w3-padding">
    <MudSelect T="string" @bind-Text="Input.Reference" @bind-Value="Input.ReferenceId" For="()=>Input.Reference" Margin="Margin.Dense" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Label="Select An Option">
        @foreach (ReferenceData reference in referenceData)
        {
            <MudSelectItem Value=@reference.ReferenceId>@leadReference.ReferenceText</MudSelectItem>
        }
    </MudSelect>
</div>

After I select a new item, how can I display @leadReference.ReferenceText instead of @reference.ReferenceId in MudSelect?
Edit:
The suggested answer does not work as @reference.ReferenceId can be repeated

This question is similar to: How to make MudSelect show text of selected option instead of value?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Instead of binding reference.ReferenceId to the MudSelect you can bind reference itself.
Then with the ToStringFunc property you can set how the object should be displayed as string.
Set T="ReferenceData", ToStringFunc="x => x.ReferenceText", @bind-Value="Input.Reference" with Input.Reference being of type ReferenceData.
<MudSelect T="ReferenceData" @bind-Value="Input.Reference" ToStringFunc="x => x.ReferenceText" ... >
    @foreach (ReferenceData reference in referenceData)
    {
        <MudSelectItem Value=@reference>@leadReference.ReferenceText</MudSelectItem>
    }
</MudSelect>

In case you can't modify input use a placeholder for the Value. And use ValueChanged to set the value of input.ReferenceId
<MudSelect 
    T="ReferenceData" 
    Value="referenceData" 
    ValueChanged="((e) => ReferenceChanged(e, Input)" 
    ToStringFunc="x => x.ReferenceText" ... >

private ReferenceData _referenceData

private void ReferenceChanged(ReferenceData referenceData, Input input)
{
    input.ReferenceId = referenceData.ReferenceId;
}

Snippet for both
Select Documentation: Custom Converter
